# we want to get all possible values with $a_1$

Tags: sequence

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Given
$$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases} \dfrac{a_n}{2}& (a_n \: \text{even})\\
n{a_n}& (a_n \: \text{odd})\end{cases},\:a_8= 10$$
we want to get all possible values with $a_1$. How can I get it using Mathematica11? Please.

Comment: You can represent this without needing piecewise: as $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} a_n \left((2 n-1) (a_n \bmod 2)+1\right)$ or even without the mod, as $\frac{1}{4} a_n \left((1-2 n) \cos \left(\pi  a_n\right)+2 n+1\right)$

Answer (score 4):

We could invert the functions and go "backwards". So, `a[n-1]` could be `2*a[n]` if `2*a[n]` is even (which it will always be, so we always have at least one possibility). But also, `a[n-1]` could be `a[n]/(n-1)` if that value is odd.

So, given a value for an index, we can compute possible previous values:

```
PreviousAs[{idx_Integer, value_Integer}] :=
  With[
    {evenCase = 2 value, oddCase = value/(idx - 1)},
    Thread[{idx - 1, {evenCase, If[OddQ[oddCase], oddCase, Nothing]}}]]
```

We're given a value for index 8, and we encode this as `{8,10}`. We want to go backwards 7 steps, so evaluate this to get the possible values for index 1:

```
Nest[Catenate@*Map[PreviousAs], {{8, 10}}, 7]
```

We can test that it works (although this test doesn't guarantee that we found them all--maybe my logic above was incomplete) by defining the "forward" function:

```
NextA[{idx_Integer, value_Integer?EvenQ}] := {idx + 1, value/2};
NextA[{idx_Integer, value_Integer?OddQ}] := {idx + 1, idx value}
```

and iterating on one of the candidates generated above:

```
Nest[NextA, <...copy/paste one of the candidates here...>, 7]
```

Hopefully we get `{8,10}` back.

Comment: The logic is fine. It seems that $a_8=10$ is not very interesting. For $a_8 = 21$, one can use your code `Nest[Catenate@*Map[PreviousAs],{{8,21}},7]` to get a more interesting solution `{{1,2688},{1,224},{1,192},{1,24},{1,6},{1,3},{1,4}} `.

Answer (score 1):

We first write the recurrence equation like: a[n_]:= ... and set a[1]=a1 where a1 is not yet known:

```
Clear[a];
a[1] = a1;
a[n_] := a[n] = If[OddQ[n], a[n - 1]/1, a[n - 1] (n - 1)];
```

Now we can get a[8]:

```
a[8]
(* 105 a1 *)
```

From this we see that a1= 10/105:

```
a1=10/105;
```

To test:

```
a[8]
(* 10 *)
```

and the whole sequence up to 10:

```
Table[a[i],{i,10}]
(* {2/21, 2/21, 2/21, 2/7, 2/7, 10/7, 10/7, 10, 10, 90} *)
```

Comment: Similar observation as per @user293787 to my answer - the `a`s need to be integers.